# I am uploading a CSV file but cannot access it in the notebook

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

[image: the csv file was added in the Quantum Lab]
[image: Screenshot of what I am doing]

I uploaded a CSV file using import in Quantum Computing Lab folder. It is uploaded, I can see it. When I write "import filename" in my notebook, it shows an error.
I have tried doing the same in my local PC. It is working fine.
What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to upload a CSV file and use it?

Comment: It might help if you add the code you are running and the error you are getting. Loading a CSV file is not done with `import csv_file` (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) so I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: @luciano I added screenshots with the code, error and uploaded file. Hope that helps

Comment: As explained in https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15272/1859, you have a spelling mistake.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

So I went to the IBM Quantum Experience to download a calibration data for Valencia just to have csv file.
[image]

Then I was able to read it in the Jupyter notebook through the IBM Quantum Lab environment as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

File names are case sensitive. `Shared_capstone_Model_csv.csv` is not the same as `Shared_Capstone_Model_csv.csv`. Change `open` code for `Shared_Capstone_Model_csv.csv` (note the `C` in `Capstone`).